# Applying Jensen's inequality to determine lower bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I want to solve this exercise:

Let $X \sim \mathrm{Geometric}(1/11)$. Use Jensen's inequality to determine a lower bound on $\mathrm{E}(X^4)$, by applying Jensen's inequality to $X^2$ with $f(x) = x^2$.

I'm not sure where to start. If it had said to apply the inequality to $X$, the answer simply would have been $(\mathrm{E}(X))^2$, correct? The issue for me is that is says to apply it to $X^2$.

Any hints?

Comment: thanks to the hint of martini the problem is now reduced to the finding of $\E[X^2]$, which is linked to the variance...you know how to proceed?

Comment: No, I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Looking at wikipedia (cheating a little) it says for the geometric distribution $\mathrm{E}[X^2] = ((1-p)(2-p))/(p^2)$ which gives me 210. And $210^2 = 44100$ which, according to the book, is wrong.

Comment: Oh, hang on! Now I know! $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ so $E[X^2] = Var(X) + E[X]^2 = 10 + 100 = 110$ and $110^2 = 12100$ which is correct. Thank you!

Comment: alright then! the computation might become a bit painful, but wiki seems to be good source for a guided tour

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake in my calculation as I recognized while cross referencing with Wikipedia, your solution should be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. As $f(x) = x^2$ is convex, for any random variable $Y$ we have
$$ \def\E{\mathbf E}\E[Y]^2 = f(\E[Y]) \le \E[f(Y)] = \E[Y^2]  $$
apply this for $Y := X^2$, as said, giving 
$$ \E[X^2]^2 = \E[Y]^2 \le \E[Y^2] = \E[(X^2)^2] = \E[X^4]. $$